# pandas Dataframe datetime sort return wrong time values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, timestamp

now im trying to sort timestamp <"Timestamp" column> like below

```
odf['FROMTIME'] = pd.to_datetime(odf['FROMTIME'])
odf['TOTIME'] = pd.to_datetime(odf['TOTIME'])
```

```
new_df = odf.sort_values('Timestamp', ascending=True)
```

[image]

and it looks like above.

time 0:51 and next time go to 10:01

in original data, there is 1:01, 1:02......timestamp

how can i sort timestamp column looks like right?

thanks for reading.

Comment: [show your data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Comment: I think problem is in `pd.to_datetime`, how looks problemtic data from question before `odf['FROMTIME'] = pd.to_datetime(odf['FROMTIME'])` ?